# How to make a Django filter display only to some users?

Tags: django, django-filters

I'm working on a Django project, and want to know how can I make it so that a filter field displays only if the user is a superuser. My filter looks like this:

```
class OrderFilter(FilterUserMixin):
    customer = django_filters.CharFilter(label='Cliente', method='filter_name')

    def filter_name(self, queryset, name, value):
        queryset = queryset.filter(customer__phone__icontains=value)
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ("store", "customer", "date")
        filter_overrides = {
            models.CharField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.CharFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'lookup_expr': 'icontains',
                },
            }
        }
```

All normal users should be able to filter by customer and date, but only superusers should be able to filter by store, the rest of users should always see the orders of a single store, so no filtering the store.

I don't know how can I accomplish this, I'm using this view:

```
class OrderTableView(LoginRequiredMixin, PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = Order
    table_class = OrderTable
    template_name = 'order/order_list.html'
    paginate_by = 50
    filter_class = OrderFilter
    formhelper_class = OrderFilterFormHelper
    exclude_columns = ('actions',)
    export_name = 'orders'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(OrderTableView, self).get_queryset()
        if self.request.user.profile.store is not None and self.request.user.is_superuser is False:
            qs = qs.filter(store=self.request.user.profile.store)
        qs = qs.filter(total__gt=0).filter(address__isnull=False).filter(location__isnull=False)
        return qs
```

Comment: That 'do something' is the problem, I don't know how to "disable" one of the filter so it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways to solve it:

```py
class OrderFilter(FilterUserMixin):
  # omit the other codes
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.request.user.is_superuser and self.filters.get('store'):
      self.filters.pop('store')
```

then drop the related code for the superuser.